# How do I insert a login if statement into FormWizard View for Django?

Tags: django, authentication, formwizard

How would I insert "if request.user.is_authenticated" into the form wizard class below like shown in the example below? The idea is this view is my homepage and I would like to redirect to a different page if the user is already logged in.

Currently it is giving me "name 'request' is not defined" as an error message. I tried class BusinessWizard(request, SessionWizardView), but unfortunately it did not work. Maybe it is a simple oversight on my part. Thank you for your help!

**views.py**

```
class BusinessWizard(SessionWizardView):
      if request.user.is_authenticated:
          HttpResponseRedirect('some url')
      else:
          #some code and functions etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to add the <s>login_required</s> user_passes_test decorator in the urlconf:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from .views import BusinessWizard

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^wizard/$', user_passes_test(lambda user: user.is_anonymous(), 'some url', None)(BusinessWizard.as_view())),
)
```

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-in-urlconf
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test

If you want to define your own decorator you can use the following snippet:

```
from functools import wraps
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .views import BusinessWizard

def anonymous_required(redirect_url=None):
    """
    Decorator that redirects authenticated users to a different URL.
    """

    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.is_anonymous():
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^wizard/$', anonymous_required('some url')(BusinessWizard.as_view())),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however this achieves the opposite effect that I am looking for. I would like the view to be shown only if the user is NOT logged in. Would there be something similar that would be able to do this for me? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part that you want to redirect users which are authenticated. By using the user_passes_test decorator and checking if user.is_anonymous() only those who are authenticated will be redirected.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Just a quick side question that I'm having trouble Googling, but would you happen to know why the "/?next=/" is showing up at the end of the url and how I would get rid of it? Ex: http://localhost/page/?next=/

Thank you!

Comment: I modified my answer. The user_passes_test decorator takes a third argument to specify the name of the redirect_field_name. When passing *None* this GET parameter is not appended to the URL. Beware that this third parameter is not officially documented in the Django Documentation.

Comment: Thank you thank you! I tried reading the documentation, guess I missed that part. You are the best!

Comment: I just added a custom decorator code to my answer which shows how this could be achieved without the use of user_passes_test. This is even cleaner and does not rely on the undocumented redirect_field_name parameter.